# Update server folder using SFTP and Pageant authentication

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sftp, pageant

Currently I am using psftp.exe on Windows 7 to recursively transfer many files and folders from a local machine to a server. I am using Pageant based authentication for that process. The mechanism works fine using "mput -r" command options.

Now I would like to *update* (or synchronize) the remote folder based on file time stamps since the amount of files and data increases significantly and I can not afford uploading the big amount of unmodified files each time.

Since the command line call is currently integrated into an C++/Qt application it could be possible to use some C++ or Qt library but due to additional implementation effort I would currently prefer to solve this using psftp.exe if possible.

Is there a way to do such an update/sync easily using psftp.exe that I missed during my research? If not, is there a replacment command that implements Pageant authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `psftp` does not support synchronization. Though you can use WinSCP. It supports scripting, synchronization and Pageant authentication as well.

See the [WinSCP guide to automating synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*